# Filling Combobox with observable list which consumed from wcf service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml, combobox

I am Beginner in WPF. I am trying to fill combobox with observable collection which is retrieved from wcf service

xaml code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbclass" ItemsSource="{Binding ClassList}" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayMemberPath="ClassName" SelectedValuePath="ClassID"/>
```

Consuming service:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client ClassList = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
ObservableCollection<ClassDO> Classlist = new ObservableCollection<ClassDO>();
Classlist = (ObservableCollection<ClassDO>)ClassList.GetClassList();
cmbclass.ItemsSource = Classlist;
cmbclass.DisplayMemberPath = "ClassID";
cmbclass.SelectedValuePath = "CLassName";
```

I am getting following error can anyone please help me?

> Error 1
>   'SchoolManagementSystem.ServiceReference1.ClassDO[]' to
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'    D:\Dotnet\Projects\WPF\WindowsPhoneApps\SchoolManagementSystem\SchoolManagementSystem\MainWindow.xaml.cs    37  23  SchoolManagementSystemCannot convert type

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @mehow S.P kill all the edits `:)`

Comment: gosh this will be a wiki soon :P

Comment: Am i wrong when i say this will not be compiling bacause the fact that your serviceclient instance has the same name as your observablecollection

Comment: first step, change name of one of two `ClassList` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this code. This example is using [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

The ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new erviceReference1.Service1Client();
        Classlist = new ObservableCollection<ClassDO>(client.GetClassList());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ClassDO> ClassList { get; set; }
}
```

The View

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ClassList}" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayMemberPath="ClassName" SelectedValuePath="ClassID"/>
```

And in the codebehind of your view set the datacontext

```
this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

In this example I assume that `GetClassList()` an IEnumerable of `ClassDO` returns

Answer (score 0):

I got how to fill combobox with observable collection whish is consumed from WCF 
Xaml Code:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Cmbclass" ItemsSource="{Binding Classlist}" VerticalAlignment="Center" DisplayMemberPath="ClassName" SelectedValuePath="ClassID" Loaded="CmbClassListLoaded"></ComboBox>
```

Consumingservice:

```
public void GetClassList()
{
ServiceReference1.Service1Client ServiceClient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
ObservableCollection<ClassDO> Classlist = ServiceClient.GetClassList();
Cmbclass.ItemsSource = Classlist;
Cmbclass.DisplayMemberPath = "classname";
//Cmbclass.se = "ClassID";
Cmbclass.SelectedValuePath = "classid";

}
```

Now call Getclasslist in windowload method